# Sobre Hooks ClassMethods Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Estou com uma dúvida no funcionamento do classmethod hooks etc

eu tenho um model:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {

    const User = sequelize.define('tb_users', {
        name: {
            type: DataType.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: DataType.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique:true,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true,
                notEmpty: true
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: DataType.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        }
    },
        {
        hooks:{
            beforeCreate: user => {
                try{
                    const result = User.findAll({
                        where:{
                            name: user.name
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                    if(result != null){
                        console.log('login já existe');
                    }else{
                        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
                        user.set('password',bcrypt.hashSync(user.password,salt));
                        console.log(user.password);
                    }
                }catch(error){
                    console.error(error);
                }
            }
        },
        classMethods:{
            isPassword: (encodedPassword, password) => bcrypt.compareSync(password, encodedPassword)   
        }
    });

    return User;
};
```

no meu class methods eu tenho essa verificação de password, mas eu tenho dúvida de como eu vou chamar ela em meu controller.
Ou como esse classMethods funcionaria.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente o uso correto para se instanciar um método no Sequelize é esse:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {

    const User = sequelize.define('tb_users', {
        ...
    },
        ...
    });

    User.isPassword = (encodedPassword, password) => bcrypt.compareSync(password, encodedPassword) 

    return User;

};
```

Para ser chamado você deve usar:

```
if (Users.isPassword(encodedPassword, password)) {
    ...    
}
```